# Loop a function until told to stop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Looking to run a function in coffeescript every minute until a value inputed by user will stop the loop (restart the loop if function called again).

Looking around I assume this has to do with setTimout and clearTimeout?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it with `setTimeout` (no need for `clearTimeout`), by re-scheduling the next call each time (`setTimeout` schedules a one-off call). Or you can use `setInterval` (which starts a repeated timer) and `clearInterval` (which stops it).

Starting a repeated timer at 60-second intervals:

```
timerHandle = setInterval yourFunctionHere, 60000
```

Or if you want to define an inline function for it:

```
timerHandle = setInterval ->
    yourCodeHere()
    return
  , 60000
```

Cancelling it later:

```
clearInterval timerHandle
```